# Django 1.7 md5crypt

Tags: django, authentication, md5

I am still very new to the django scene, still learning basics, and would aprecciate some pointers on how to solve this issue.

I was tasked with upgrading a django website from 1.3 to 1.7 and transfer the apps from 1.3 to 1.7, I was able to create a testing project with authentication to the admin page using the default authentication, but when I looked at the auth_user table of the 1.3 version I noticed the authentication was done in md5_crypt in the following format (md5crypt$salt$hash), i tried using passlib 1.6.2 to no avail, changing md5crypt to md5_crypt in the database password field.

Can someone point me in the right direcction on how to add md5crypt password capabilities to a default configured django 1.7 project?

Comment: How is the 1.3 project using md5crypt? What is the `PASSWORD_HASHERS` setting in the 1.3 project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appear to have solved this problem, I found a module to encrypt in md5crypt in our django 1.3 machine and went to my django /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/hashers.py file and defined a new hasher class:

```
#imported md5crypt.py module that I moved to /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/
from django.contrib.auth import md5crypt

class MD5CryptPasswordHasher(BasePasswordHasher):
"""
The Salted MD5crypt password hashing algorithm
"""
algorithm = "md5crypt"

def encode(self, password, salt):
    assert password is not None
    assert salt and '$' not in salt
    cryptedpassword = md5crypt.md5crypt(force_bytes(password), force_bytes(salt))
    cryptedpassword = cryptedpassword.split('$',2)[2]
    #change from $1$ to md5crypt$
    return "%s$%s" % (self.algorithm, cryptedpassword)

def verify(self, password, encoded):
    algorithm, salt, hash = encoded.split('$', 2)
    assert algorithm == self.algorithm
    encoded_2 = self.encode(password, salt)
    return constant_time_compare(encoded, encoded_2)

def safe_summary(self, encoded):
    algorithm, salt, hash = encoded.split('$', 2)
    assert algorithm == self.algorithm
    return OrderedDict([
        (_('algorithm'), algorithm),
        (_('salt'), mask_hash(salt, show=2)),
        (_('hash'), mask_hash(hash)),
    ])
```

My password hashers settings.py:

```
PASSWORD_HASHERS=(
 'django.contrib.auth.hashers.MD5CryptPasswordHasher',
 'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2PasswordHasher',
 'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2SHA1PasswordHasher',
 'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptPasswordHasher',
 'django.contrib.auth.hashers.SHA1PasswordHasher',
 'django.contrib.auth.hashers.MD5PasswordHasher',
 'django.contrib.auth.hashers.UnsaltedMD5PasswordHasher',
 'django.contrib.auth.hashers.CryptPasswordHasher',
)
```

I can't share with you the module md5crypt.py because I don't have permission for that, security reasons.